# Update User Password From Table Using Bash

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bash

My bash script is using mysql query to execute the command, but when I try to put in my password that it reads in it still gives me an error.

```
printf 'Wordpress Password?:\n'
read -e wrdpressPass
```

Here is my mysql query:

```
mysql> use "$fulldb" << EOF
other mysql queries....
....
UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = MD5('"$wrdpressPass"') where id=2 LIMIT 1;  
EOF
```

Note: Already logged in as root user so password is not required when using mysql commands. Also tried it as

```
UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = MD5("$wrdpressPass") where id=2 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Why do you have both double and single quotes? Should only have single quotes

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Comment: I suggest to use `mysql` command for this job.

Comment: i already am using the mysql command, you are supposed to wrap variables in double quotes.

Comment: No errors, it overwrites the current password, but it doesn't let me login with the password that I made for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively changing your password to `$wrdpressPass`, that means NOT the content that you've entered, but **literally** `$wrdpressPass`.

The shell expansion does not work from within the mysql command.

If you include everything in one script, it will work:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf 'Wordpress Password?:\n'
read -e wrdpressPass

echo "Found ${wrdpressPass}"
mysql -v -u root db_name -p << EOF
SELECT * from wp_users;
UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = MD5("$wrdpressPass") where id=2 LIMIT 1;
SELECT * from wp_users;
quit
EOF
```

This will also show you that the changes to the row were made.

If you still can't login, are you sure that you want to change the login password for the user with the `id=2`?